# How do I remove an image node with the given src attribute?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, xpath

I need to remove an image with the give src

```
img_src = "http://domain/img.jpg"
@doc.xpath("//img[@src='#{img_src}']")[0].remove
```

Doesn't work. Tried it also like this

```
@doc.xpath("//img[@src='#{img_src}']") {|x| x.remove}
```

Doesn't work either. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**I got it. It was a stupid mistake. All your solutions were correct.**

Comment: What does _"doesn't work"_ mean here? Do you get an error? No error but the doc is unchanged? Have you tested to see if you can find the correct element before attempting to remove it?

Comment: It would help to see a more complete example of how you are parsing the file.

Comment: @Greg, @Phrogz, I've updated topic with the full example and some details. Thank you for your helping.

Comment: ok, I got it. A stupid mistake as I thought.

Comment: NP. Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) has two different parser modes, one for XML and one for HTML. XML is strict and HTML is very relaxed because, well, HTML is not always well-behaved.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<xml><a>1</a></xml>')
```

or

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body>foo</body></html>')
```

This is how I generally [parse an HTML file](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/wiki/):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.com'))
print doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
[...]
```

To strip a tag you need to locate it first, then `remove` it. After we parse a HTML or XML document we'll have a Nokogiri::HTML or Nokogiri::XML document respectively, and, at that point what we called "tags" are now called "nodes". Nokogiri can find nodesets, which are nodes that match a search, or an individual node, which will be the first match from a search.

This will search for the first node matching `src="a.png"` using a CSS accessor, which is generally easier/cleaner than XPath. Nokogiri understands both XPath and CSS very well, and there are some advantages to CSS mentioned on the website:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

html = '<html><body><img src="a.png" /><img src="b.png" /></body></html>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.at('img[@src="a.png"]').remove
print doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body><img src="b.png"></body></html>
```

To locate all nodes matching the accessor you could replace `doc.at('img[@src="a.png"]').remove` with:

```
doc.search('img[@src="a.png"]').each { |n| n.remove }
```

The [tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials) are worth reading too.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = <<ENDXML
  <root>
    <img src="http://foo/foo.jpg" />
    <img src="http://bar/bar.jpg" />
  </root>
ENDXML

doc = Nokogiri::XML xml
img_src = "http://foo/foo.jpg"

doc.at_xpath("//img[@src='#{img_src}']").remove

puts doc
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <root>
#=> 
#=> <img src="http://bar/bar.jpg"/>
#=> </root>
```

Comment: Doesn't work with me :( Does it make any difference if I open a document as HTML? (it's actually a html page)

Comment: @Arty What versions of Ruby and Nokogiri?

Comment: What do you mean "open a document"? Nokogiri can try to figure out whether a document is HTML vs XML, but it's not an overly smart "decisionator". You're better off telling it what type of document it is, by using either `Nokogiri::XML()` or `Nokogiri::HTML()` to parse the content.

Comment: @Arty Some things in Nokogiri change depending on whether you use XML or HTML, but the node is removed for me with HTML as well. I'm on Ruby 1.9.2 and Nokogiri 1.4.4 on OS X.

Comment: @Phrogz I'm using ruby 1.8.7 and nokogiri (1.4.4, 1.4.2).

Comment: @Greg, thanks for your detailed explanation, I've tried to repeat the same, but node is still not removed. I can locate it and change any attribute I want, but when I use .remove on it - it's just doesn't work. It makes me think that probably it's some sort of stupid mistake somewhere if you all gave me same examples they should have been working.

Comment: @Greg, and yes, I open a document in HTML mode

Comment: @Arty As seen in [this pastie](http://pastie.org/1354596) the above works fine for me using 1.8.7, 1.4.4, and HTML mode.